# Error while submitting a request to an ASPX page using Python

Tags: python, asp.net

I was experimenting my skills in Python, and I tried to write a little script in python that will send a request to find out which data center is the website is located at using the option "network whois record"

Therefore I used the following website :

http://centralops.net/co/DomainDossier.aspx

and I wrote the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "http://centralops.net/co/DomainDossier.aspx"
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml; q=0.9,image/webp,*/*; q=0.8',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Connection' : 'keep-alaive',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                'Accent-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
                }
        # All taken from the source page of the website.
FormFields = ((r'_VIEWSTATE',''),(r'addr',r'yahoo.com'),(r'dom_whois','off'),(r'dom_dns','off'),(r'traceroute','off'),(r'net_whois','on'),(r'svc_scan','off'))

encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(FormFields)
req = urllib2.Request(url,encodedFields,headers)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

but the issue comes when I try to execute the file and it gives me the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "data_center.py", line 18,
in <module>
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Access denie
```

So please, can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Look at the last line of the error: "HTTP Error 403: Access denied". Does the website accept automated requests?

Answer (score 1):

As Flight Odyssey suggests they might be blocking automated requests.

Change you code so it prints the url instead of submitting and try pasting it manually to make sure you get to the right page - there may be another step / captcha etc.

Also, not sure if it is a typo but your header says

```
  'Connection' : 'keep-alaive',
```

Comment: This is only possible in GET cases am I right ? can you please give it a try cuz I'm not yet sure where my mistake at ? I mean I guess you all agree that my code is alright logically, isn't ?